# Is there a way to automate updating the same image in a large number of InDesign Documents?

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, automation

I need to update one image in a large number of InDesign documents with a new image.  I'm hoping there is a way to batch automate this process, similar to find and replace.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just replace the actual image with the new one?

Answer (score 1):

As Janus eludes to in the comments...

Find the old image in your file system, add "-Old" to the file name, then drop your new image into the same location and title the file the same title as the old image. When you open any InDesign file using that image, it will either auto-update to the new image or ask you if you want to update modified images.